# Force javascript to load absolutely last

Tags: javascript

I have a 3rd party javascript that claims to be coded to load after my page is loaded. I can't edit the code of this javascript. However, I must run my scripts after this javascript. Is there any numerical configuration to set the load order? e.g. if the 3rd  party script is 1000 i will set mine to be 10000000

Comment: Do you mean page loaded or DOM loaded?

Comment: please show how you are linking these js files

Comment: Nope, only the natural order of your script tags, as long as they are'nt async.

Comment: Does the 3rd party script allow you to attach event handlers?

Comment: `if the 3rd party script is 1000 i will set mine to be 10000000` Or you could set it to 1001 :)

Comment: If this 3rd party script is changing something you can monitor, after loading you can easily check for this "change" and load your scripts on this event.

Comment: If it's using the `window onload` event and doing so in a way you can attach multiple `window onload` events, then setup your script to run after `window onload` but set that up after the other script runs and adds it's handler.

Comment: It's a chat box script, here is the embed code.. not using window onload to my knowledge.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/AKHK68B7

Comment: Why not just tell us that you're using olark, as showing us minified and obfuscated code does'nt really help much. There are no known issues with this regarding the olark code, and olark is used "everywhere", so I'll take a wild guess and say you're doing something else wrong to make this an issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you know one of the 3rd party scripts function names, you can check for when that function is loaded then execute your script.

```
var scriptCheck = setInterval(function(){
    if(typeof thirdPartyFunctionName == 'function') { 
        console.log('script loaded'); // DO STUFF 
        clearInterval(scriptCheck);
    }
}, 1000);
```

or maybe it's `window.thirdPartyFunctionName`